# Query replace a copied string by another copied one

Tags: copy-paste, query-replace

**Use case:** I want to:

1. copy a (long, not handy to manually type) `newstring`,
2. replace all occurrences of another (long, not handy to manually type)
   `string` by `newstring`.

**Current process (not handy):**

1. Copy (mark + `M-w`) `string` in the (main) buffer.
2. Start the query replace process, using copied `string` (`M-% C-y <RET>`).
3. Select another window (`C-x o`) to switch from the minibuffer to the main
   one.
4. In the (main) buffer, (optional: search (`C-s`) for `newstring` and) copy
   (mark + `M-w`) `newstring`.
5. Select another window (`C-x o`) to switch from the main buffer to the
   minibuffer.
6. Paste (`C-y`) `newstring` and continue the query replace process (`<RET>`).

**Possible start of track:** [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/203026/1682470) provides the a nice way (`C-s C-w`) to *search for* the word after the current mark.

**Question:** I wonder if:

1. the previous track could be extended to *replace* for the word after the
   current mark,
2. or if there is another, better, track for my use case.

Answer (score 3):

Avoiding window switching:

1. Copy `string`
2. Copy `newstring`
3. <kbd>M-%</kbd><kbd>C-y</kbd><kbd>M-y</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd>
4. <kbd>C-y</kbd><kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>-1</kbd><kbd>M-y</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd>

Or if you can get used to copy `newstring` before `string`:

1. Copy `newstring`
2. Copy `string`
3. <kbd>M-%</kbd><kbd>C-y</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd>
4. <kbd>C-y</kbd><kbd>M-y</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd>

And another option is to write function which will call `query-replace` with most recent kill ring entries and bind it to some key. Then just:

1. Copy `string`
2. Copy `newstring`
3. <kbd>key for my/query-replace-function</kbd>

Comment: Not as handy as I would expect (I hoped something like in the spirit of linked answer), but works indeed :)

Comment: `C-y M-y` is quite handy. You have all of your past kills and copies available in a ring. You can just cycle `M-y` to get to the one you want. Or you can use [Browse Kill Ring](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BrowseKillRing) to choose any of them. Or you can use menu `Edit` > `Select and Paste` to choose one.

Comment: Or you can use the [secondary selection](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SecondarySelection) for either of the pastes (yanks). The secondary selection stays, even as you change the region or copy/kill other selections.